# Validate large data on web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, large-files, validation

i have the following case

- customers upload big excel files concurrently (10 K +records(4+ MB)) this will take some time.
- i need to do validation on data structure after upload and this will take more time.

i thought maybe it's better to handle data validation separately (offline), either by using a **Windows Service to validate the data** and generate errors reports or **submitting data to Que using MSMQ** (which is more reliable).

**which approach is better ?**